# could a switch perform better in multiplayer games over the internet?

Tags: ethernet, switch, gaming

I use to play with my friends Age of Empires 2 at Voobly..Sometime we all go to same house to play all togheter. 
With voobly we need to use internet and all de notebooks are connected via Wifi to the router. But sometimes some players get slow speed and high ping for a moment.

so... if i put a switch connected to the router, and all the pc connected via ethernet cable to the switch, will the connection improve and get more stable? maybe better ping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, without a doubt. Wifi at its best can be fast but Ethernet will be vastly more stable. Look for switches capable of Gigabit Ethernet (on all ports) - it won't cost you much more than 100M Ethernet. I'm using Linksys but would be fine with Netgear, D-Link, TP-Link.

Comment: Hi Joe, what about this one? http://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-42_TL-SG108.html
@JustAGrump

Comment: Looks fine but that's a separate question!

Comment: It's not a separate question - shopping questions are totally off-topic.

Comment: Agree, a separate question for an separate site altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. While you can get into the technical aspects of trying to find the higher speeds of LAN speed based on the router wi-fi, its a much more stable line and you don't need to worry about wi-fi interference.

Comment: thanks, can you recommend a model of switch for this?

Comment: @RatiosSistemas I normally like netgear for simple applications like this. I would go to amazon and just find one with the amount of ports you need. No need for PoE switch, so your cost should be fairly low.